# nightwatch listen for custom event

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to test for a Javascript CustomEvent in Nightwatch. My website performs a CustomEvent call upon display or click on certain elements (for external analytics tracking). By example: when the page loads, and a banner is displayed, a custom event "banner-displayed" will be fired (custom event is attached to the body element); on clicking the banner, the banner-clicked custom event is fired.

I want to test when I navigate in my test environment (nightwatch-selenium-phantom) to the page, the banner-displayed event is fired, and when I perform a 'click' command on the banner, the banner-clicked event is fired.

Can't figure out how to set up the right script and command logic to get this done... Any help appreciated.